# Image Size is limited in Lightbox2

Tags: lightbox2

i just download the sample of lightbox2 and use the css & js to create my lightbox successfully. However , i found the image is not the original size when i'm click the enlarge (it suppose is larger).  Does it the css or js setting limited the size?

Look forward your prompt reply.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The lightbox re-sizes the image in its native behavior at the level javascript in 2 cases :

**Case 1**

If the properties maxWidth/maxHeight are set in the options :

**maxWidth**    -   If set, the image height will be limited to this number, in pixels. Aspect ratio will not be maintained.

**maxHeight**   -   If set, the image width will be limited to this number, in pixels. Aspect ratio will not be maintained.

**Case 2**

If the image width or height is > than the containers width, you can check the `changeImage` function in the [lightbox.js](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/src/js/lightbox.js) for more information

```
// part of the code where resize checking occurs
    ...
            maxImageWidth  = windowWidth - self.containerLeftPadding - self.containerRightPadding - 20;
            maxImageHeight = windowHeight - self.containerTopPadding - self.containerBottomPadding - 120;

         // Is there a fitting issue?
                if ((preloader.width > maxImageWidth) || (preloader.height > maxImageHeight)) {
                  if ((preloader.width / maxImageWidth) > (preloader.height / maxImageHeight)) {

    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `fitImagesInViewport` option that is set to true by default. Any images that would extend outside of the viewport are resized so they fit neatly inside of it.

If you would like to view images at their full resolution, and are okay with images extending outside the viewport, then you need to set this option to false.

```
<script src="path/to/lightbox.js"></script>
<script>
    lightbox.option({
      'fitImagesInViewport': false
    })
</script>
```

A list of all available options is available here:
http://localhost:8000/dist/#options